# EOFException when restarting my app on Android

Tags: codenameone

I loose values in Preferences (CN1Preferences) in particular scenario of using my application on Android.

When I launch my app the first time, I save some values in Preferences. If I close my app (from background task) and then I sleep my tablet, when I relaunch the app, values save in Preferences are lost. This is the log I obtain after the relaunch :

```
    CliniScore: [EDT] 0:0:0,4 - Exception: java.io.EOFException - null
05-04 16:32:40.667 10618-10978/? W/System.err: java.io.EOFException
05-04 16:32:40.667 10618-10978/? W/System.err:     at java.io.DataInputStream.readBoolean(DataInputStream.java:69)
05-04 16:32:40.667 10618-10618/? D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
05-04 16:32:40.667 10618-10978/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.io.Util.readObject(Util.java:541)
05-04 16:32:40.667 10618-10978/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.io.Util.readObject(Util.java:638)
05-04 16:32:40.667 10618-10978/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.io.Storage.readObject(Storage.java:261)
05-04 16:32:40.667 10618-10978/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.io.Preferences.get(Preferences.java:83)
05-04 16:32:40.667 10618-10978/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.io.Preferences.get(Preferences.java:298)
05-04 16:32:40.667 10618-10978/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneImplementation.initEDT(CodenameOneImplementation.java:235)
05-04 16:32:40.667 10618-10978/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:952)
05-04 16:32:40.667 10618-10978/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
05-04 16:32:40.667 10618-10978/? W/System.err:     at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
05-04 16:32:40.667 10618-10978/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

If I force close my app only (without sleep my tablet), there is no problem with my preferences values.

This problem doesn't occurs in iOS/Simulator/Emulator(Android). I've only noticed it on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A running Android 6.0.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you placed an object into preferences that implemented externalizable incorrectly is that possible?

Comment: No, I've only primitive types in preferences. I've an object that implement externalizable, but it's placed in another file and it seems correct

Comment: Did you do something else like encrypted storage or anything? 
Did you write to the cn1preferences file? Did you change the path of the preferences file?

Comment: I manually encrypted some String in the preferences file (with my own algorithm AES). Yes I write to the CN1Preferences file and didn't change the path

Comment: I read comments of this article : https://www.codenameone.com/blog/preferences-location-popup-order.html
It seems that Peng encountered same behavior. One difference is I don't use at all EncryptedStorage...

Comment: The encryption case for that post "corrupted" the file. The question is how that can happen if you don't do that. I'll need a way to reproduce this

Comment: I think I've resolved my problem (further tests will (or not) confirm that). The problem is I had put too many treatments in destroy() method as logout of user (switching a boolean in Preferences). I think in Android, it execute only a part of destroy() which then corrupted my preferences file

Comment: This problem reappear, so my solution doesn't work ... I will think about a test case but it's very difficult to extract only the code that contains the issue

Comment: I would suggest avoiding the destroy() method entirely and using it only in extreme cases. It isn't guaranteed anyway... I understand the difficulty of extracting a test case here, I would suggest on-device-debugging but since the failure happens at a different point (file corrupted and only later do you get the exception) this would be pretty hard to debug

Comment: Maybe it's linked with thread safe and file writing. I mean, Preferences class is not thread safe, and if we access to it from different thread, it's possible that it corrupted the file.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that this relates to threaded access to the preferences which should be legal. I've made the two potentially disruptive methods synchronized in today's update and hopefully this would resolve that issue.

Comment: I didn't notice any change

Comment: Then I doubt it's a race condition

Comment: I didn't find the commit in github containing your modification. Could you give me the link ?

Comment: It seems git lost my changes F*CK!!! I'm trying to get a sense of what else I committed that was lost and see no record of several different changes!

Comment: I've seen that you recommit the fix. It seems that it correct my issue ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem recurred :(

Comment: Are you sure it's not with an older version of the app that is still sending logs?

Comment: I mean the problem recurred when testing my app on Android with current version of codenameone. I've compiled this version yesterday

Comment: I've found I write in preference in destroy method. It might be possible it doesn't write correctly and corrupt the preferences file, when force closing my app. Then, when I reopen the app, the preferences file is corrupted.

Comment: Destroy is a very problematic method. You should avoid it whenever possible. We considered not including it at all when we initially created the lifecycle mapping and that might have been a better choice...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I copied a working project to start a new one. And I left the file 
`keystore.jks` (keystore to upload to Google Play) empty, so when I compiled I got this exception.

I just removed the *signingConfig* line in `android/buildTypes` section in the application level `build.gradle`, and it worked.

May be you had a problem of this kind, an empty forgotten file that shouldnt be empty.